# How to $http.Post the Values to a Subdoucment of Mongoose Schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Iam New for the  Mongoose and Mongo :-

```
    var Tag = new Schema({pno: NUMBER,_id:false,id:false});
// Myshcema 
    var mySchema= new Schema({

            Name: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
                trim: true,
                required: ' Name cannot be blank'
            },
            phones:[Tag ],
            email:String,
            services: [Tag],
            address :{
                city : String,
                zip : Number,
                loc:[string]
            }

        });
```

Angular UI:-
 <

```
div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="pno">Phone Number</label>
                    <div class="controls"><div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="pno" data-ng-model="pno" id="pno" class="form-control"  placeholder="pno"></input>
                    </div></div>
                </div>
```

POST METHOD:-

```
var resObj = {
                Name: this.Name,
          address{
                city:this.city, // Fields from address sub document
                zip :this.zip //  Fields from address sub document

               },
               phones:[this.pno]// Actually itis not working

            };

Post i used from Client side :-

                var res = $http.post('http://localhost:3000/service', resObj);
```

**Methods For saving Api from Server side :-**

```
    exports.create = function(req, res) {
    Var newapi= new Service(_.extend(req.body));
        newapi.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(newapi);
        }
    });
};
```

But when i posted Successfully  ... the result is not  good ..

```
Result :-


{"_id":"6b01c0e00b2e7b3",Name:'service name',**"phones":[null],"services":[]**,"address":{"loc":[]}}

**address.city is not Filling the Value**
```

**How can I fill the **Phones** , **service**  **and  how do we Post Sub    document Values** ?** 
   Honestly i have got no idea of it ... Please some one Help me By Answering ... Thanks A Lot In Advance!!!

Comment: Is it possible to show how you are saving the document in your API? The phones field is an array, you need to post an object with the same schema i.e. `var resObj = {Name: this.Name, address: { city: this.city, zip: this.zip }, phones: [this.pno] }`.

Comment: Iam using Something Like this resobj.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
   return res.status(400).send({
    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
   });
  } else {
   res.json(resobj);
  }
 });

Comment: Added it i just changed some naming conventions for  some reasons But the Logic is Same ..

Comment: Have you tried changing the your `resObj` to match that of the `Service` schema e.g `var resObj = { Name: this.Name, address: { city: this.city, zip: this.zip }, phones: [this.pno]  }`?

Comment: Yes it worked for address  fields ... trying the Tag one

Comment: the Pno is Sending    result "phones":[null]

Comment: Let me Update the code what i did for Pno

Comment: Added the new code Please Take a look .. you just Did  Undo for Your Answer please Post it .. I can accept

Comment: The `phones` property of the `resObject` should have an array as value so change it to how I showed in my answer i.e. `phones: [this.pno]` not `[phones:this.pno]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72779/discussion-between-prasad-and-chridam).

Comment: Yes TAG array worked with some changes Can I Update your answer with that changes ? is that Okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phones field is an array, you need to post an object which matches your `Service` schema i.e. change how you create your `resObj` object:

```
var resObj = {
     Name: this.Name,
     address: {
        city: this.city,
        zip: this.zip
     },
     phones: [
        this.pno
     ]
}
```